# Maxima for Android (and PC as well): How to reuse the result of a calculation

Tags: maxima

Let's say I enter this symbolic calculation in Maxima for Android:

```
integrate(sin(x)*x,x)
```

The answer is beautifully displayed thanks to MathJack (it is sin(x)-x*cos(x)). Ok, thanks. But now I would like to tap in that answer and have it in the command line, ready to be modified (for instance I may want to multiply it by some number and then use it in another calculation).

What I want is something similar to pressing the "ANS" key in some calculators, where the last result the machine yielded can be used as new input.

In Xcas Pad this is easy and straightforward (just touch on the result, that's all). How to do that in Maxima for Android? (The answer for the PC version of Maxima is also appreciated).

Remark: Copy-paste does not work in Android, because the answers are Latex-formatted or something similar.

Comment: You can refer to the last answer with `%`. E.g. entering `% * 8`. I have not found any way to actually edit the resulting expression other than copy-pasting.

Comment: @Juancho Tanks Juancho, but copy-pasting does not work in Android, since the output expressions are latex or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

You can tap the answer formula displayed with Mathjax in the main area. The maxima expression will be entered in the bottom command area, as you wanted.

Actually, the commands displayed in the main area are also tap-able. You can tap one of them and it is entered in the bottom command area.